# Cannot insert into mysql table from Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, joomla

I am trying to run this query via Eclipse to a local Joomla mysql database:

```
INSERT INTO jos_content (title, alias, catid, created_by, created, state) 
VALUES ('Reuben Morgan','reuben-morgan',15, 86, ' 2013-06-10 11:33:58 ', 1);
```

But I keep getting the error:

Field `introtext` doesn't have a default value.

I have set the sql-mode in **my.cnf** to "" but I get the same error no matter what I set the mode to. The same query above runs without issue on PHPMyadmin and on the commandline.

Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

Can't post the table schema coz I can't upload an image and pasting text ruins the formatting. The field 'introtext' is not null. I'm wondering how to get Eclipse to ignore that, the way the commandline is ignoring it, or at least to understand why the commandline and browser client don't throw an error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'introtext' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at edit.NiaClasses_V2.writeNewListings(NiaClasses_V2.java:207)
    at edit.NiaClasses_V2.generateNewListings(NiaClasses_V2.java:70)
    at edit.NiaClasses_V2.getSchoolList(NiaClasses_V2.java:113)
    at edit.NiaClasses_V2.getConnection(NiaClasses_V2.java:33)
    at edit.NiaClasses_V2.main(NiaClasses_V2.java:170)
```

Comment: exactly what the error message is telling you. try: `INSERT INTO jos_content (title, alias, catid, created_by, created, state, introtext) VALUES ('Reuben Morgan','reuben-morgan',15, 86, ' 2013-06-10 11:33:58 ', 1, '');`

Comment: Can you please post schema of your table?

Comment: @darijan this should work, as you are already supplying the value to the introtext column, whereas the user is missing this column in the original query.

Comment: The problem is that the same query runs on the mysql commandline and the browser client but not from Eclipse. Why?

Comment: @Stoleg user said that same query worked when ran from command line.          User: You should paste schema of table here so that we can have a look.

Comment: @darijan, I tried that already. It then complains about the next field that doesn't have a default value. The table has 34 columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I had this line

```
sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

run inside my java program via a Statement object, right after creating a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Change entry in you mysql.conf to `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and then restart your mysql server.

Alternatively, restart your mysql server with `--sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`
It should work :)

Comment: Can you try to change mode from your sql session itself: set SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

Comment: I've set the session from inside the Eclipse project, and now I have a different error, but I think I can handle that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you @viny. Setting the sql mode on my.cnf didn't work but setting it from within the java program has solved the issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what ends up in the table if you insert incomplete rows with this sql mode enabled?

Comment: Autocomputed default values for that column. Check MySql documentation for sql_mode

Comment: FYI, when I run (`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'; SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`) from the mysql terminal, this works ONLY until the next mysql restart. But when I try to make that permanent in [mysqld] section of my.cnf with sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" (with or without quotes) and restart the mysql server, it doesn't work. I have to run the commands manually again. Any ideas why my.cnf setting isn't being referenced on restart?